# Concourse CI: Quickstart + localhost

Tags: concourse

I've just started 'kicking the tires' on Concourse-CI, using the [quickstart tutorial](https://concourse-ci.org/quick-start.html) as my starting point. That much works fine.

I've created a super basic pipeline with a single task, just like the quickstart tutorial.  But instead of pulling the busybox image and executing the echo command, I'm pulling another image, and running a command that would try to update a local postgres db.

When I run the pipeline - my task (docker image writing to local postgres db) fails - because connection can't be made to the local db.  I've searched far and wide - and can't seem to figure out how to do this.  In the docker-compose from the quickstart tutorial, I've tried adding `CONCOURSE_CONTAINERD_ALLOW_HOST_ACCESS: "true"` to no avail

Any suggestions on how I may be able to achieve this?

Comment: Please post more details, including what is the exact error message you're getting.

Comment: thanks for replying.  turns out my issue had nothing to do with concourse - see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my issue had nothing to do with Concourse.

The local postgres instance I was attempting to write to was only accepting connections from localhost - which won't allow connections from Docker containers.  I updated postgres setting to allow remote connections - and all is well.